# new kernel compile - error on bootup - Could not find overlay

Tags: linux, kernel, boot

I was compiling the kernel using slackware-current, the latest version of the kernel, 4.3.3, also tried 4.4-rc5, and ran into this error on bootup

```
Could not find overlay #6 ### dt-test ### of unittest_destroy_tracked_overlays: overlay destroyed failed for #6
```

It kept scrolling over the screen, the system didn't boot any further.

So I looked up the message on the internet and ended up on this Q&A forum, 
This post to be exact.

[Error when booting new kernel - overlays](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/232976/error-when-booting-new-kernel-overlays)

I'm still compiling with the suggested solution, yet there is also a message that the error can not be reproduced, which is totally wrong, since I have the same error.

Can anybody tell me the exact reason(s) why this happened?

PS. I'm compiling this on an old Pentium 4 Celeron 3.06GHz with 768M RAM, so no need to rush

PPS. After disabling **Device Tree Overlay** ( CONFIG_OF_OVERLAY=n )in the kernel config file, the resulting kernel boots. Yet still no understanding of the reason it fails to boot when enabled.